# Some coloring only visible if I set `hi Normal guibg=NONE`?

Tags: neovim, colorscheme

I just encountered one more tricky coloring problem. If I set `hi Normal guibg=NONE` I will get the effect I want:

[image]

But if I disable the transparent background by setting that `guibg` to anything else, I will get:

[image]

I have zero knowledge about how to solve this, please help!

p.s. I made the two image clickable so if it's too small to see the difference just click!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so happy that I finally found the answer myself, simply do:

```
hi TermCursor guifg=NONE guibg=NONE
```

[image]